# How to add commas to a list of variables in SAS

Tags: sas

I am new to SAS so please forgive my ignorance if this question seems simple (in other languages it is a rather trivial task).
How can I convert a list of variables within a `%Macro`:

`%Let var_list = var1 var2 var3`

Into this

`"var1","var2","var3"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a FAQ but I did not find another question to link to.
You can use the TRANWRD() function to convert the spaces into `","` (as long as the resulting string is less that data step maximum of 32,767 bytes).  Make sure to reduce multiple spaces to one.

```
%let var_list = var1   var2   var3 ;
%put "%sysfunc(tranwrd(%sysfunc(compbl(&var_list)),%str( ),%str(",")))" ;
```

Results:

```
"var1","var2","var3"
```

Comment: I love this one. I saw you post it somewhere on SAS Communities a while ago and it's one of the tricks I've come across. I converted it into an fcmp function called `cquote` that I use all the time in the data step, sql, and in macros. Users can enter space-separated lists for macros or program variables, then they're converted to the correct format later. E.g. `%let exclude = A B C; %let excludecq = %sysfunc(cquote(&exclude));"`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [mf_getquotedstr()](https://core.sasjs.io/mf__getquotedstr_8sas.html) function from the SASjs [Macro Core](https://github.com/sasjs/core) library and do it in one line:

```
%Let var_list = var1 var2 var3;

%put %mf_getquotedstr(&var_list,quote=D); /* D for Double quote */
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Without using the SASjs Macro Core library:

```
%let var_list = var1 var2 var3;
%let var_list=%bquote(")%qsysfunc(prxchange(s/\s+/%nrbquote(",")/,-1,&var_list))%bquote(");
%put &=var_list.; /* VAR_LIST="var1","var2","var3" */
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me share a little bit improved version, with pure SAS macro code:

```
%let var_list = var1 var2 var3;
%put &var_list.; /* var1 var2 var3 */
%let new_var_list = "%sysfunc(prxchange(s/\s+/"%str(,)"/, -1, &var_list.))";
%put &new_var_list.; /* "var1","var2","var3" */
```

A little bit easier to read/understand than Kermit's proposal which is pretty good  of course!